# getting object properties and classes

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I'm trying to get the relation below: ***dog owner has pet dog*** [image]. I do that using the following code:

```
   for(OWLClass clazzzz : ontology.getClassesInSignature()){

         if(clazzzz.getEquivalentClasses(ontology).size()!=0 ) { 

for(OWLClassExpression ax: clazzzz.getEquivalentClasses(ontology)) {

                OWLObjectVisitorAdapter visitor = new OWLObjectVisitorAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce) {
                    for (OWLClassExpression e : ce.getOperands()) {
                if ( e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature().size()==1  )
                            {
System.out.println(clazzzz.getIRI().getFragment()+" ---> "+e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()+" ---> "+ e.getSignature() );

                        }

                    }

}
                };

                ax.accept(visitor);

            }
         }
     }
```

It works, but I need to get the object property and the class ***dog*** separately: I mean ***dog*** as a class and ***has-pet*** as the object property instead of getting the whole expression containing both of them.
Another question: My code must return all classes of the ontology being part of the expression but by skipping cases when we have restriction with ***complementOf*** this case must be skipped, if you have any idea how can I reformulate this condition into my code. for example, vegetarian in the example below shouldn't be taken into account by my code:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peoplePrétraitée#vegetarian">
        <owl:equivalentClass>
            <owl:Class>
                <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peoplePrétraitée#animal"/>
                    <owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peoplePrétraitée#eats"/>
                        <owl:allValuesFrom>
                            <owl:Class>
                                <owl:complementOf rdf:resource="http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/peoplePrétraitée#animal"/>
                            </owl:Class>
                        </owl:allValuesFrom>
                    </owl:Restriction>
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Indeed, you have to cast the OWL class expression, in your example, it's an object of type `OWLObjectAllValuesFrom`, then you can get property and filler concept. Indeed, the filler concept itself is an OWL class expression. Here, the same principle, cast to the appropriate object. Note, as don't know in advance, you should use a visitor to do those things, as OWL class expressions can be arbitrarily nested.

Comment: For getting independently the object property and concepts it works by using this without cast : e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature().iterator().next().getIRI().getFragment() AND e.getClassesInSignature().iterator().next().getIRI().getFragment());

Comment: Concerning the second question about skipping restriction with complementOf I didn't understand how can I use cast and visitor

Comment: Your method is a bit weird, it just uses the signature of the class expression. Please understand that an `OWLClassExpression` is just a Java interface, one of its implementations being `OWLObjectAllValuesFrom` which exactly represents the class expression type of your example. And that's the only useful way of processing class expressions with OWL API. You can check the type of the filler concept, i.e. whether it's a negation. To be honest, your method fails if the whole class expression is more complex, i.e. your implementation is far away from being generic.

Comment: I know it's weird as a solution. I'm not familiar with the API and OWL generally. It took me days to understand your comments .... Thank you for you and @Ignazio for helping

Answer (score 0):

As @AKSW suggested, the best approach is to use a visitor, specifically an `OWLObjectVisitor`. You can extend `OWLObjectVisitorAdapter` for convenience, as you only need to carry out actions on specific objects encountered.

So, for visiting the parts of the expression you've already found:

```
final OWLObjectVisitor v =new OWLObjectVisitorAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce) {
                for (OWLClassExpression e : ce.getOperands()) {
                    e.accept(v);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(OWLClass c){
                System.out.println(c);
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(OWLObjectProperty p){
                System.out.println(p);
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(OWLObjectComplementOf e){
                // do nothing for complements
            }
}
```

Comment: I try to apply the solution you proposed by I have problem with e.accept(v); the error I get is : "the local variable may not have been initialized "

Comment: My mistake. Replace e.accept(v) with e.accept(this)

Comment: I still can't make an operating code using your proposition. I put into brackets of visit() functions simple outputs as you did, but I can't get any result... But it works when I put ax.accept(v) at the end as I did for the code I proposed before .. what is the difference I can't understand

Comment: ax.accept(v) is necessary because that's where the visitor starts executing.

Comment: Even when I use visitors, I still get cases containing ComplementOf, since there're cases within the intersection expression. So, they're returned by the first function public void visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce). What I need, is to filter results of this function to get only those which not contain ComplementOf(Class). As in the given example, the class expression defining for vegetarian... must be skipped.

Comment: Once you visit `ComplementOf` just skip whatever you're doing, otherwise do whatever you're doing. That's the whole idea of traversing a class expression with a visitor recursively.

Answer (score 0):

As @AKSW suggested I cast the owlclassExpression and use filler. you can find the updated version. 
But as he said, it's not a generic solution. Any idea to make it generic. have I keep as argument of visit function OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce and treat each case independently ? I mean OWLObjectAllValuesFrom and OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom .. Anyway I need to test on other ontologies to get all possible cases.

```
 @Override
                        public void visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce) {
                            for (OWLClassExpression e : ce.getOperands()) {
                                if ( reasoner.isSatisfiable(e) && e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature().size()==1  && e.getClassesInSignature().size()==1 )
                                 {      
                                        if(e.getClassExpressionType().equals(ClassExpressionType.OBJECT_ALL_VALUES_FROM) )
                                        {   System.out.println("---------------");
                                            OWLObjectAllValuesFrom all = (OWLObjectAllValuesFrom) e;
                                            all.getFiller();
                                            System.out.println(clazzzz.getIRI().getFragment()+" ---> "+ e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature().iterator().next().getIRI().getFragment()+" ---> "+all.getFiller());
                                            nbrRelations++;
                                        }   
                                        else 
                                        {System.out.println("---------------");
                                        System.out.println(clazzzz.getIRI().getFragment()+" ---> "+ e.getObjectPropertiesInSignature().iterator().next().getIRI().getFragment()+" ---> "+e.getClassesInSignature().iterator().next().getIRI().getFragment());
                                        nbrRelations++;
                                        }



                                }
                               // e.accept(this);     

                            }

                        }
```

Comment: Yes, to make it generic, you'll have to implement all methods of the visitor. To make it a bit more simple, OWL API contains classes like [`StructureWalker`](https://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/util/StructureWalker.html) which traverses all entities in axioms/class expressions recursively.

Comment: Ok. And Concerning this case I put in the example of visit(OWLObjectIntersectionOf ce), there is a way to treat cases generally, or I need to test all possibilities of the class Expression type and cast it As you proposed for OWLObjectAllValuesFrom. because filler it's returned just for OWLObjectAllValuesFrom and OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom